# Kafka Streams - why no GlobalKStream?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Kafka Streams provides three main ways to consume messages from a topic: the KStream, KTable and GlobalKTable. I like to think of each in the following way:

- KStream - consume all messages for each key from the assigned partitions.
- KTable - consume only the latest messages for each key from the assigned partitions.
- GlobalKTable - consume only the latest messages for each key from all partitions.

Why isn't there a GlobalKStream, i.e. the ability to consume all messages for each key from all partitions?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you could route the events through a topic with a single partition. I wouldn‘t recommend this, but that would be a way to do it. Simply put: there is a good reason to distribute the data and the workload between topics and consumers within a consumer group.

Comment: I mean partitions not topics

Comment: There was no feature request for this yet :) -- what is your use case? Why do you need this?

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6646
There actually is a feature request for this, though it has been inactive since being filed in 2018.